# Getting issue 'Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}' in react type script

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I am facing an issue when I am try to access object with id in the below code. Getting an error message like 'Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'' . Here Id is string.

```
export type testProps = {
  isOpen: boolean;
  question: QuestionData;
};

export type QuestionData = {
  id: string;
  text: string;
};

const Test = ({ question }: testProps) => {
  const { appState, appAction } = useAppContext();
  
  const { submitted } = appState;
  const submittedAnsId = submitted && submitted[question.id]; // Getting error at this line
   // format of submitted data => {Q1: {Q1A1: 'test'}, Q2: {Q2A3: 'abc'}}
}

export default Test
```

Comment: The problem could be related to the type of the type of the `submitted` object, what's the definition of `useAppContext`?

Comment: type appState = {submitted: object}, this type mention in useAppContext for appState. The submitted is dynamic , it will update when user perform action. So that's the reason provide the formate of submitted data

Comment: Alright, if `submitted` is a generic object then TS might complain like in your case. If `submitted` is a hash map mapping `questionId` to some specific object type, how about you use a `Record<string, WhateverObjectTypyYouNeed>` type?

Comment: I tried this way  type SubmittedAnswer = {
  [key: string]: string;
}; type appState = {submitted: SubmittedAnswer}; Can you please provide bit more specific way to handle if u know this one ?

Comment: able to resolve thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Need to define type in this way in context

```
type appState = {submitted: Record<string, object>;}
```